# Scope by custom attribute or excluding data by scope

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Model User that has a polymorphic relation to table `Relationships` with Pivot column `relationship_level`.

```
public function activities()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Activity', 'relationship')->withPivot('relationship_level')->withTimestamps();
}

public function relationships()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Relationship');
}
```

I want one the following:

I want `scopeNoCitizens` which to exclude everyone who has a relationship_level `Citizen` no matter what other relationships he has.

I've tried:

```
scopeNoCitizens($query) {
    $query->whereHas('relationship', function($query) {
        $query->where('relationship_level', '!=', 'Citizen');
    });
}
```

This doesn't work, maybe because all users have many levels and I want everyone who has even one record among many that has level `citizen` to be excluded from the collection.

I also have a custom attribute getHighestRoleAttribute, but as far as I understand you can't filter by accessor/custom attribute in a scope.

What I currently do is "filter" the collection after `get()`, but I have to manually paginate after that and do that on numerous places in the app.

Comment: Have you tried    $query->wherePivot('relationship_level', '!=', 'Citizen'); ?

Comment: The first argument for `whereHas()` should be the method name for the relationship, in you case that would be `relationships`, not `relationship`